# used .join(something) but result is not joined

Tags: python, sql

The result I'm expecting is

```
>>> message_to bits('')
''
>>> message_to_bits('hello')
'0110100001100101011011000110110001101111'
```

But what I get is an error for the empty string and for strings, only the 1s and 0s for the first character:

```
def char_to_bits(char):
    """char_to_bits(char) -> string

    Convert the input ASCII character to an 8 bit string of 1s and 0s.

    >>> char_to_bits('A')
    '01000001'
    """
    result = ''
    char_num = ord(char)
    for index in range(8):
        result = get_bit(char_num, index) + result
    return result

def get_bit(int, position):
    """get_bit(int, position) -> bit

    Return the bit (as a character, '1' or '0') from a given position
    in a given integer (interpreted in base 2).

    The least significant bit is at position 0. The second-least significant
    bit is at position 1, and so forth.

    >>> for pos in range(8):
    ...     print(b.get_bit(167, pos))
    ...
    1
    1
    1
    0
    0
    1
    0
    1
    """
    if int & (1 << position):
        return '1'
    else:
        return '0'

def message_to_bits(message):
    for char in message:
        result="".join(str(bits.char_to_bits(char))) 
    return result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to join twice:

```
def message_to_bits(message):
  return "".join("".join(str(bits.char_to_bits(char))) for char in message)
```

The first join is for the bits in a char, and the second is for the chars in the message.

Comment: but what about the empty string??

Comment: @hwanghyungchae: For an empty string input, the `for char in message` generator should produce an empty iterable, so the result should be the empty string, right? Sorry, I'm on a tablet at the moment and can't verify the result.

Comment: you don't have to apologize dude. i got it now i put this :  if len(message)==0:
        return ''

Comment: @hwanghyungchae: I verified interactively that this should work without an explicit check: `''.join('123' for char in '')` returns `''`.  And if you want to do an explicit check, I would just check `if message:` instead of `if len(message) == 0` -- the first form is more Pythonic.  Lastly, if you found this answer helpful, feel free to vote it up and/or accept it.

Comment: i don't have enough reputation to vote up. anyways, thank you very much!